# Processing PVector heading() formula

Tags: vector, processing

Anybody know the formula that Processing uses in PVector heading()?
[PVector::heading](https://processing.org/reference/PVector_heading_.html)

Thanks a lot

Comment: Processing is open source. Like [Tordek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48050384/873165) says, you can just look up the implementation yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [its implementation](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PVector.java) it uses the arctan function. The tangent of an angle is the ratio of the opposite and adjacent sides' lengths (y/x), and arctan is the inverse function of the tangent, i.e., it returns the angle for which the tangent is (y/x).